# Gmap3 show all the available markers on the map from database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am using [gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net/) to show google map. In my case I have stored all the information of properties in the database(mysql) with custom markers. Now I want that when the page is loaded it will display all the markers in google map.
For loading googlemap with gmap3 plugin I am using this code

```
function loadMap() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof gMap == 'undefined') {
      //// CREATES A MAP
      gMap = jQuery('#map-canvas');
      gMap.gmap3({
        map: {
          options: {
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            streetViewControl: false
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

and inside div ``map-canvas I can see the map. But can some one kindly tell me how to show all the markers with the positions? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

**Update**
If I am wrong with my codes then someone can show their codes to me. I am using Gmap3 plugin.

Comment: In above code you are not reading any data about makers

Comment: yes..that I want to know how to show all the available markers from the database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about this it will work in gmap3 but i use this code for creating my costome icon hope it will help you

In the index.php use this for creating your costom icon pathlike this

```
<?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
     $result = mysql_query($query);     
    $a=array();
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $a='$row[\'type\']'=>array('icon'=>'$row[\'path\']','shadow'=>'$row[\'path2\']')
    }     
        $a=json_encode($a);
        ?>
```

it should be done before js file after that
write this

```
<script>
        var customIcons= <?php echo $a; ?>;
    </script>
```

and finally load your map and infoWindowbox() in that function

```
function infoWindowbox() {
     downloadUrl("xml.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
              var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
              var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
              var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
              var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
              });
              markerArray.push(marker);
              bounds.extend(marker.position);
              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
          });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

gmap3 initializator has a marker attribute that allows you to create markers.

See example with single and multiple markers here:
http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41

Comment: is this good to use like this or should I use xml data to show the markers?

Comment: Yes gmap3 accepts only this way (javascript object in initializator). If you have data in XML you should write a php parser that generates the JavaScript syntax or a JavaScript parser that uses addMarker to dynamically add markers after initialization

Answer (score 0):

I think this [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/categories.htm) might help.

**Updated:**

If you want to read the data like from database (or) xml, You can then make an ajax request to that page (from any page on your site) using jQuery:

I have an example but this is with xml to get the data from xml file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'categories.xml (or) your database path',
  type: 'get',
  success: function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var html = "<b>"+name+"<\/b><p>"+address;
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }

        // == show or hide the categories initially ==
        show("theatre");
        hide("golf");
        hide("info");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();
      });

      });
```

Like this you may get the data from database also through using queries. Try this one atleast you may get the idea.

Comment: Yes I want that type but the documentation is poorly written. I am not getting it properly...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

[The gmaps3 plugin documentation](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41) shows how to add markers. If you create an options array in php through ajax/json and feed that to the `markers:` option  your markers should be added.